# "ValueError: _type_ 'v' not supported" error after installing PyReadline

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ipython

After I installed PyReadline, IPython won't work. When I uninstalled it, it starts working again.

The stack trace for ipython:

```
(py2.7_monitor)[root@vm10-136-8-98 monitor]# ipython
WARNING: IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 118, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 591, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 314, in initialize
    self.init_shell()
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 330, in init_shell
    ipython_dir=self.ipython_dir, user_ns=self.user_ns)
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 380, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 531, in __init__
    self.init_readline()
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1941, in init_readline
    import IPython.utils.rlineimpl as readline
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/rlineimpl.py", line 21, in <module>
    _rl = __import__(_rlmod_name)
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyreadline.rlmain import Readline
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyreadline/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import logger, clipboard, lineeditor, modes, console
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyreadline/clipboard/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .win32_clipboard import GetClipboardText, SetClipboardText
  File "/home/py2.7_monitor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyreadline/clipboard/win32_clipboard.py", line 37, in <module>
    import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ctypes/wintypes.py", line 23, in <module>
    class VARIANT_BOOL(_SimpleCData):
ValueError: _type_ 'v' not supported
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[As stated](http://ipython.org/pyreadline.html) on their site, the `PyReadline` library is Used for **Windows**.

Looking at the last lines of your stack trace:

```
import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ctypes/wintypes.py", line 23, in <module>
class VARIANT_BOOL(_SimpleCData):
ValueError: _type_ 'v' not supported
```

It is trying to import windows specific data types from `ctypes` which is obviously not possible since you are not running Windows.

Comment: This applied to my case also, Msys2 under Win10. I simply removed `pyreadline` with `pacman -Rs mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyreadline` and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

This will likely help exactly no one in the year 2020 or beyond, but all the same I want to record it here for posterity.

I experienced the same `ValueError: _type_ 'v' not supported` traceback with an installation of Python 2.7.16 in an HPC cluster environment, attempting to install [pdbpp](https://pypi.org/project/pdbpp/), which depends on [fancycompleter](https://pypi.org/project/fancycompleter/), which depends on pyreadline, which imports `ctypes.wintypes` and is affected by this [this core Python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue16396) from 2012.

It's true that `ctypes.wintypes` should never be imported on a non-Windows platform (Cygwin, MSYS2, and Git Bash are technically non-Windows, since they will have a *real* GNU Readline library and don't need the pure Python shim).

However if it *were* imported on a non-Windows platform, because of the issue mentioned above, `ctypes.wintypes` throws a `ValueError` instead of an `ImportError`, which means that a typical `try`/`except` that expects to catch an `ImportError` will just blow up because of the unhandled exception.

Pdbpp's fancycompleter, or rather pyreadline, somehow fell victim to this. I get confused about who's to blame, because fancycompleter's `setup.py` isn't supposed to bring in pyreadline as a dependency [*except* on Windows](https://github.com/pdbpp/fancycompleter/blame/master/setup.py#L32), but somehow **there it was** on my Linux system. And *if* it's there, fancycompleter tries to import it.

All I can figure is I may have had an old fancycompleter in my pip cache with a typo in its `setup.py` that was pulling in pyreadline when it shouldn't have, because it *was* grabbing that dependency, time after time.

What actually finally resolved this situation for me was to `pip uninstall pyreadline`, then `pip install -U --ignore-installed --no-cache-dir fancycompleter` to get a "fresh" version of fancycompleter that did not bring in the unnecessary pyreadline dependency.