# Msys2 upgrade breaks python2-pyqt5

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt5, upgrade, msys2

I am using msys2 from PortableApps, under Win 10.

When I try a full upgrade with `pacman -Syuu`, I get

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 mingw32                                                                   456.6 KiB   773 KiB/s 00:01 [###########################################################] 100%
 mingw32.sig                                                               119.0   B  0.00   B/s 00:00 [###########################################################] 100%
 mingw64                                                                   459.4 KiB   792 KiB/s 00:01 [###########################################################] 100%
 mingw64.sig                                                               119.0   B  0.00   B/s 00:00 [###########################################################] 100%
 msys is up to date
:: Starting core system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace bzr with msys/breezy? [Y/n] n
:: Replace mingw-w64-x86_64-pygobject-devel with mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-gobject? [Y/n] y
:: Replace mingw-w64-x86_64-pyqt5-common with mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt5? [Y/n] y
:: Replace python3-appdirs with msys/python-appdirs? [Y/n] y
:: Replace python3-attrs with msys/python-attrs? [Y/n] y
:: Replace python3-packaging with msys/python-packaging? [Y/n] y
:: Replace python3-pip with msys/python-pip? [Y/n] y
:: Replace python3-pyparsing with msys/python-pyparsing? [Y/n] y
:: Replace python3-setuptools with msys/python-setuptools? [Y/n] y
:: Replace python3-six with msys/python-six? [Y/n]
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing mingw-w64-x86_64-pyqt5-common breaks dependency 'mingw-w64-x86_64-pyqt5-common' required by mingw-w64-x86_64-python2-pyqt5
```

It looks to me that I would not be able to retain python2-qt5.

**Is there any workaround for that?**
I could keep answering *no*, but I guess I should give up at some point.

Note 1: I wonder if there is any connection with the packages reported as requiring update and [Msys2 with python 3.8: ImportError: cannot import name 'open_code' from 'io'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028653/msys2-with-python-3-8-importerror-cannot-import-name-open-code-from-io?noredirect=1#comment108379103_61028653)

Note 2: I never installed any package with `pip`, but always with `pacman`.

Answer (score 0):

I am **not completely sure** how to solve your problem, but I would imagine that

- *Reinstalling python and these packages may help*

and if not,

- *Downgrading problematic packages to previous versions may help.*

once again **not sure** if this will help, but I at least hope it points you in the right direction.