# How do I fix python 3.8.5. error "ImportError: cannot import name 'open_code' from 'io' (unknown location)"

Tags: python, python-3.8, platformio

I'm a complete novice as far as python is concerned, but need to install it for PlatformIO. I installed python-3.8.5-amd64.exe on Windows 10 and installed PlatformIO in VSCode. But when I try to do a build I get:

```
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\io.py", line 54, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'open_code' from 'io' (unknown location)
```

Since io.py is installed as part of the python installation, I assume the 'open_code' symbol should be installed. Running the Repair option from python-3.8.5-amd64.exe and rebooting claims everything's fine, but it still fails.

Can someone explain, in simple terms, what I need to do to fix this?

Note: there's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028653/msys2-with-python-3-8-importerror-cannot-import-name-open-code-from-io) which indicates it's due to there having been 2 versions of python installed and that something's pointing at the wrong verison, but it doesn't explain how to fix it in any way that I understand (as well as being for a Linux installation).

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add a [mre] to demonstrate the problem. We can't help without seeing the code that's causing the error.

Comment: Also... you didn't happen to name your python file `io.py`, did you?

Comment: That's what the traceback is supposed to look like...

Comment: @MattDMo OK, so it's the Marlin firmware that I'm trying to build. I haven't edited any python files except to confirm that line 54 of io.py is an import. This worked yesterday, but then I realised I had a 32-bit version of python installed which caused other problems, so I uninstalled it and tried installing the 64-bit version. As I said, I'm a complete python novices, so have no idea how to produce a "minimal reproducible example". I'm assuming this is an installation problem and someone will know which environment variable or registry setting didn't get cleaned up when I uninstalled.

Comment: Have you rebooted since you uninstalled the 32-bit version and installed the 64-bit one? That works wonders sometimes.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try checking your environment variables for `PYTHONPATH`, and if present what its value is.

Comment: to save u lots of headaches, uninstall everything, reboot ur comp and reinstall everything, then tell us if its successful.

Comment: @StarNamer I recommend you to use a python package manager like [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads) sometimes packages won't install properly on windows due to non-compatible built-packages. Also, it gives you the chance to run multiple instances of different python versions.

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, at least twice!

Comment: @CYREX Unistalling both python and platformio and rebooting didn't help because, it seems, platformio doesn't actually remove everything. So on a reinstall, it just puts everything back the way it was before.

Comment: @Souhailhimself I don't want to run/use any python packages. The only reason to install python was because PlatformIO uses it. Although it's a popular language, I have no desire to add it to my list of known languages (I've been programming for 45 years and the list is long) and I don't intend writing anything in it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to delete the .platformio folder from my user folder. Obviously, PlatformIO was 'remembering' the previous python install and confusing things!

Comment: That worked for me as  well. Once. When I made a couple of changes to Marlin and tried to rebuild, the problem was back. Was this a permeant fix for you?

Comment: I think I found a poor work-around. Platformio was finding my Python 3.8 installation (which was on my path). I suspected that was the problem after seeing that the same was happening to you.

Renaming the Python 3.8 folder (as a quick fix so it's contents were no longer on the path) fixed the issue. This, of course, will probably narf something else that needed to find that version of Python.

Comment: @casterle I haven't had a problem since (more than a month) so, in that sense, it has been a 'permanent' fix.

Comment: I think you're right. I have this error and solved by just deleting any python folder inside .platformio folder. I just guess that will appear again if platformio is updated.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me when multiple versions of Python was installed , and the PATH environment variable had a python path whose version was different from what i was executing. Adjusted the path variable to demote the unused python version and promote the currently used version and it solved the problem.thanks!